# The specific widget that could not find a MaterialLocalizations

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am trying to make a rating dialog but it seems to work in IOS and not in android, the error is simply 'The specific widget that could not find a MaterialLocalizations'.I even tried to include the code in build widget instead of initstate but it didn't work. Here is my code for main.dart initstate.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {




// This widget is the root of your application.


MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

RateMyApp _rateMyApp = RateMyApp(
preferencesPrefix: 'rateMyApp_',
minLaunches: 1,


);

 @override


void initState() {
super.initState();

_rateMyApp.init().then((_) {
  // TODO: Comment out this if statement to test rating dialog (Remember to uncomment)
 //  if (_rateMyApp.shouldOpenDialog) {

    _rateMyApp.showStarRateDialog(
      context,
      title: 'Enjoying Flutter Rating Prompt?',
      message: 'Please leave a rating!',
      onRatingChanged: (stars) {
        return [
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Submit'),
            onPressed: () {
              if (stars != null) {
                _rateMyApp.doNotOpenAgain = true;
                _rateMyApp.save().then((v) => Navigator.pop(context));

                if (stars <= 3) {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                  // Navigator.push(
                  //   context,
                  //   MaterialPageRoute(
                  //     builder: (_) => ContactUsScreen(),
                  //   ),
                  // );
                } else if (stars >= 5) {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                  // showDialog(...);
                }
              } else {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }
            },
          ),
        ];
      },
      dialogStyle: DialogStyle(
        titleAlign: TextAlign.center,
        messageAlign: TextAlign.center,
        messagePadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
      ),
      starRatingOptions: StarRatingOptions(),
    );
    //  }
});
```

**Code for showStarRateDialogue**

```
 Future<void> showStarRateDialog(
BuildContext context, {
String title = 'Rate this app',
String message = 'You like this app ? Then take a little bit of your time to leave a rating :',
@required List<Widget> Function(double) onRatingChanged,
bool ignoreIOS = false,
DialogStyle dialogStyle = const DialogStyle(
  titleAlign: TextAlign.center,
  messageAlign: TextAlign.center,
  messagePadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
),
StarRatingOptions starRatingOptions = const StarRatingOptions(),


 }) async {
if (!ignoreIOS && Platform.isIOS && await _channel.invokeMethod('canRequestReview')) {
  return _channel.invokeMethod('requestReview');
}

assert(onRatingChanged != null);
return RateMyAppStarDialog.openDialog(
  context,
  title: title,
  message: message,
  onRatingChanged: onRatingChanged,
  dialogStyle: dialogStyle,
  starRatingOptions: starRatingOptions,
);
```

}

Side Note: I am using Rate My App package if anyone has experience with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you’re are trying to access context for the dialog in your root class.